# Keras model and TF Lite converter

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite

I'm new to TF and I've a curiosity: in case I had to convert to TF Lite a Keras model that uses an op unsupported by TF Lite which has to be registered, how could I use the converter to convert the model and to force itself to allow custom ops at the same time (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom)?

For example, suppose we have this very simple model and pretend that Conv2D is an op not supported by TF Lite:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Model / data parameters
num_classes = 10
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Scale images to the [0, 1] range
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255

# Make sure images have shape (28, 28, 1)
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = keras.Sequential(
[
    keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
    layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
]
)

batch_size = 128
epochs = 15

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])
```

How can I use the TF Lite converter in order to allow the custom op Conv2D by following the tutorial (which in reality isn't a custom op)?

Answer (score 0):

In the conversion layer, it is not easy to make the Conv2D op to be a custom op since the TFLite converter always favors the builtin operator.

However, there are some workarounds:

(1) You can manipulate the TFLite file by using the flatbuffer library. You can make some operators in the graph as custom ops manually.

(2) You can modify the TensorFlow Lite source code for Conv2D operator if there is any need for your case.

TFLite Conv2D operator is one of the well optimized operators in the TFLite builtin operators. It might be better not to replace it with the custom op for the performance.

Comment: Please upload a new post about that with enough information. It would be better to keep each post focused.